# Filter cities by state in Simple_form Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using simple_form to create my scaffolding forms in my current project. I need some help to improve my address CRUD. After my db:seed there are lots of cities registered.

My current form for address is:

```
<%= simple_form_for @address, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do   |f| %>
<%= f.input :street%>
<%= error_span(@address[:street]) %>
<%= f.input :zip%>
<%= error_span(@address[:zip]) %>
<%= f.label :city_id %>
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id , City.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
<%= error_span(@address[:city_id]) %>

<%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            address_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

How can I filter my citties collection bellow selecting first the state ?

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the output for City.all? and what is Cidade?

Comment: Corrected, my form was in portuguese, just changed now to ask here. Cidade is city so my fault The output for City.all is the name of the city and the value as id

Comment: got it, so you want to sort city by state name? is that it?

Comment: Yes, before today I had just a few cities for test, now after my db:seed I have 5.000 cities. So maybe filter by id or a search would fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this class method to your model:

```
def self.by_state
  order('state DESC')
end
```

Then use it in your form:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id , City.by_state, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
```